# Compare SKSpriteNode texture attributes

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm currently playing with SpriteKit framework and I need to compare two ore more textures of my nodes, but the `==` operand will not work and the when I test the `print(mySprite.texure)` console will show up

`<SKSpriteNode> name:'mySprite' texture:[<SKTexture> 'logo' (400 x 400)] position:{409.60000610351562, 384} scale:{1.00, 1.00} size:{110, 110} anchor:{0.5, 0.5} rotation:0.00`

How can I obtain just the string of the texture? ('logo' in my case)
it is NOT a SKNode, I am using a SKSpriteNode.

I'm developing in swift 2.0

Comment: What kind of information do you want to compare? The image files used for the textures?

Comment: Yep. I am using the same image file for 2 or more nodes.

Comment: What about setting `name` property for your nodes? You can compare the `name` string.

Comment: I know; but I need to compare the images because I need to catch the moments when the nodes have the same images.

Comment: Show us an example for better understanding. It seems that your node's texture will be updated after the initialization?

Comment: Many parts of my code are written in italian I'm afraid. Anyway I'm printing the texture attributes of 2 different nodes and although they are identical (in both the complete syntax and just the image file name) the == operand does not recognize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two SKTextures that use the same image are not necessarily the same SKTexture; an SKTexture "wraps" the image data and provides other stuff, like filtering modes, so that you can display the same image texture in multiple ways.  That's why simply comparing them with "==" and expecting that to evaluate to true when the same image is being used won't work.

A better approach, if you want your two SKSpriteNodes to behave in a particular way when they have the same image, is to make a subclass of SKSpriteNode that tracks that logical state, and then compare those.  Let the SKTexture reflect that state, as well.  In other words, compare out of your model space instead out of your view/implementation space.  That way, if you later want to have two different textures be able to "match" in this way, you can handle it, or if you want the same textures to not "match" in this way because of some other consideration, you can handle that, too.